# Debate, Bare plurals and Injustice

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, generic

In high school debate, we have resolutions or topics. This month our topic is, "In the United States criminal justice system, jury nullification ought to be used in the face of perceived injustice." Many debaters will end up specifying a certain type of injustice e.g. they will claim a certain law is unjust and juries ought to nullify in this situation only.

On previous debate topics there has been a lot of debate over whether this is grammatically accurate. Some people have argued that certain terms in the resolution are a generic bare plural and thus specification is incorrect. Is that the same for this situation? Is there some other grammatical rule that is violated by specifying?

With regard to Henry Wu's similar question. That question is similar but does not completely answer my question. I was wondering if the topic must be interpreted generically. Deadrat's answer does not answer the question completely because it seems to appeal to the idea that perceived injustice is a generic term without a modifier;however, this idea is not justified.

Comment: Click on the link in the "Possible duplicate" comment.  Does my answer to Henry Wu's almost-identical question on 10/25 help?

Comment: Surely the mass usage is meant to include all [alleged] forms / instances (where the slash may mean 'and' _or_ and/or). Nobody is going to be able to address all forms, never mind all instances, in less than a few weeks. And I very much doubt that an argument not identifying at least one form, or not using actual examples, would be of much value. // I hope you mean '... they will claim a certain law is unjust and limit their argument to juries' duty to nullify in this particular  situation.' at the end of your first paragraph....

Comment: Colin Fine answers the usage rather than the pragmatics question in the duplicate: Like many abstracts, _injustice_ is normally a mass noun, **but can be used as a count noun. In fact I detect two different meanings for a count noun: 1) an instance of injustice; 2) a class or type of injustice.** [bolding mine]